# MySQL Trigger delete after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am really new creating triggers, but I need something really easy but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Basically I have a table this the following structure

```
Table Name orksegment
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| direction       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duration        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| localEntryPoint | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| localParty      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| loginString     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| portName        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| remoteParty     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sessionOffset   | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tapeOffset      | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| port_id         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| session_id      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tape_id         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want that if in the record that I just inserted the `localParty` is like '192%' the record be deleted.

I did something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Delete_recordings_MoH
  AFTER INSERT
  ON  orksegment
  FOR EACH ROW 
 delete from orksegment where localparty like '192%';
```

But when I do this it looks like all the entries are getting deleted because I don't get any new records in the table.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger which before the insert looks for the new column value of localParty and insert the record if it is not like '192%'

I think this code will work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON orksegment FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.localParty!='192%') THEN 
    INSERT INTO orksegment(all the column names) VALUES(New.columnA, New.ColumnB etc);
END IF
END
$$
```

Please let me know if this worked for you.